# php not throwing an Exception in function overriding

Tags: php, oop, overriding, class-design

I have a class named `DataBoundObject` which is quite big. And works good. Its an ORM class i have developed. One of its functions is to automatically do the setXXX() and getXXX() functions so that no coding is required. The following function does that

```
public function __call($strFunction, $arArguments) {
        $strMethodType = substr ( $strFunction, 0, 3 );
        $strMethodMember = substr ( $strFunction, 3 );

        if(!is_callable(array($this, $strFunction)))
            throw new Exception("Function cannot be called!"); 

        switch ($strMethodType) {
            case "set" :
                return ($this->SetAccessor ( $strMethodMember, $arArguments [0] ));
                break;
            case "get" :
                return ($this->GetAccessor ( $strMethodMember ));
                break;
            default :
                throw new Exception ( "Non existent method call dude!" );
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now in a class which derives this i override one function like this:

```
<?php

require_once ('DataBoundObject.php');
/** 
 * ORM extension of BUBBLES_HOTEL_REVIEWS Tabel
 * @author footy
 * @copyright Ajitah
 * 
 */
class reviews extends DataBoundObject {
    protected $ReviewID;
    //Other codes

    private function setReviewID($ReviewID) {
        throw new Exception ( "Cannot set the review ID Explicitly" );
    }
    //Other codes
    //Other codes
    //Other codes
    //Other codes
    //Other codes    
}
$x = new reviews();
$x->setReviewID(5);

?>
```

Thus finally i create a new object and try to call `setReviewID()` function which is private. Why is it not generating any `Exception`? Besides `is_callable()` is returning true!

**EDIT**

Mainly i need help to correct this problem so that it throws an `Exception`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override *private* methods using __call magic in PHP. I allow myself to quote from php.net website http://php.net/language.oop5.visibility#92995, where your question is perfectly answered in a comment:

> 1. In the overriding, the method names and arguments (arg’s) must be
>      same.
> 2. final methods can’t be overridden.
> 3. private methods never participate in the in the overriding because
>      these methods are not visible in the child classes.
> 4. While overriding decreasing access specifier is not allowed

If you desperately need this feature - your (unconventional) options will be:

1. Use public scope for the method, documenting the function of its restrictions for other developers in PHPDoc string.
2. You can use PECL extensions like *runkit* sandbox http://php.net/book.runkit
3. Go for code generation or preprocessor.
4. Choose a different language.

**EDIT**

Note that, *protected* child method is also hidden form the parent, but there is always an option of overriding __call() in a child. Generally, making too much "magical" overrides may be a bad taste for such a serious undertaken as ORM design.

PS

I believe eventually developing a DSL could be an ultimate goal for your project. Before doing so, continuing your project is a nice way to gather respective experience. GL!

Comment: Making the `setReviewID` public from private seams to do the trick for now. But is it bad practice? How can i avoid this in future implementation

Comment: In your case public scope is completely sound, since your code $x->setReviewID(5); shows that you mind this method to be accessed as public. As long as you call private method inside the same php class it would be accessed before parent::__call(). Thus avoiding this situation automatically.